# TeamCity 9 - Disable user registration

Tags: teamcity

I own a TeamCity build server that I use for publishing development builds for projects I have. Problem is, users can register an account. I want it so users can only be created on the administration tab. How do I do this?

Comment: Feels like this should be disabled by default.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### To disable new user registration on login

> 1. Go to the Administration| Authentication page.
> 2. Click the edit link in the table next to the Microsoft Windows domain authentication description.
> 3. Uncheck the Allow user registration
>      from the login page box.
> 4. Click the edit link in the table next to the NTLM HTTP authentication description.
> 5. Uncheck the Allow user registration from
>      the login page box.

Source [TeamCity 9.x Documentation - Configuring Authentication Settings](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Authentication+Settings)

Comment: hidden away from view :@